# How to control Energy Balance e.g. KE must remain below 5-10% of Internal Energy, in Abaqus Explicit while performing Quasi Static Analysis?

Tags: abaqus

Im trying to perform progressive collapse analysis of RC frame on Abaqus Explicit solver. At the end of job when I check Kinetic energy and Internal Energy I found very little difference between both energies which is not valid for performing Quasi Static analysis.
Can someone help me that How I can control this energy balance? I mean which parameters I should consider to keep KE below the total internal energy?

Comment: Can you check if [this](https://www.researchgate.net/post/How_to_reduce_kinetic_energy_in_abaqus) helps your case? Also, I think that this question fits better in [physics.stackexchange.com](https://physics.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Collapse is a dynamic process, so no wonder that you have important kinetic energy. Also, you are using the Explicit solver is treating the problem as dynamic one. You can try Static solver with stabilization or Implicit Dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but since kinetic energy is proportional to velocity squared, reducing the boundary condition velocity will reduce your kinetic energy. Alternatively, if you are using displacement control, increase the amount of time it takes to ramp up to the desired displacement. Lastly, a thing you can do to reduce KE is to reduce the mass-scaling (if you are using that).